# Count occurrences of unique arrays in array

Tags: python, numpy, counter

I have a numpy array of various one hot encoded numpy arrays, eg;

```
x = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]])
```

I would like to count the occurances of each unique one hot vector,

```
{[1, 0, 0]: 2, [0, 0, 1]: 1}
```

Comment: What have you tried? [so] generally frowns upon questions where one hasn't shown an attempt to solve their own problem.

Comment: list is unhashable, you cannot use it as a key in a dictionary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Seems like a perfect setup to use the new functionality of [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)  (v1.13 and newer) that lets us work along an axis of a NumPy array -

```
unq_rows, count = np.unique(x,axis=0, return_counts=1)
out = {tuple(i):j for i,j in zip(unq_rows,count)}
```

Sample outputs -

```
In [289]: unq_rows
Out[289]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0]])

In [290]: count
Out[290]: array([1, 2])

In [291]: {tuple(i):j for i,j in zip(unq_rows,count)}
Out[291]: {(0, 0, 1): 1, (1, 0, 0): 2}
```

---

**Approach #2**

For NumPy versions older than `v1.13`, we can make use of the fact that the input array is one-hot encoded array, like so -

```
_, idx, count = np.unique(x.argmax(1), return_counts=1, return_index=1)
out = {tuple(i):j for i,j in zip(x[idx],count)} # x[idx] is unq_rows
```

Comment: Note `axis` was added in numpy 1.13, so previous versions can't use this method..

Comment: Approach #2 might work better with the `np.eye` trick for one-hot arrays. `u, count = np.unique(x.argmax(1), return_counts=1)` ,`i = np.eye(np.max(u))`, `out = {i[u]:j for i, j in zip(u, count)}`.  That way you don't need `return_index` or to index the big one-hot vector in your loop.  Also hooray for `np.unique(...,axis)`!

Comment: And then we can go down to the answer by @TemporalWolf and realize we're wasting our time doing `np.unique` at all with one-hots when we could just be summing over the second axis.

Comment: @DanielF Thanks! Yes, would work with `np.eye(np.max(u)+1)`. Also, `summing` along the first axis would work, just the additional work of masking out the `zero` counts and corresponding the counts to their respective rows if I got that correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You could convert your arrays to tuples and use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
x = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]])
Counter([tuple(a) for a in x])
# Counter({(1, 0, 0): 2, (0, 0, 1): 1})
```

Comment: This is the only one that works with strings (or object type) in python 3.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way given your data format is:

```
x.sum(axis=0)
```

which gives:

```
array([2, 0, 1])
```

Where the 1st result is the count of arrays where the 1st is hot:

```
[1, 0, 0] [2
[0, 1, 0]  0
[0, 0, 1]  1]
```

This exploits the fact that only one can be on at a time, so we can decompose the direct sum.

If you absolutely need it expanded to the same format, it can be converted via:

```
sums = x.sum(axis=0)
{tuple(int(k == i) for k in range(len(sums))): e for i, e in enumerate(sums)}
```

or, similarly to tarashypka:

```
{tuple(row): count for row, count in zip(np.eye(len(sums), dtype=np.int64), sums)}
```

yields:

```
{(1, 0, 0): 2, (0, 1, 0): 0, (0, 0, 1): 1}
```

Comment: @EricDuminil Does that edit help? if not, I'll add more explanation... the index of the the sum is also the index of the hot.

Comment: Okay, got it. I didn't know what "one hot" means. Nice.

Comment: @EricDuminil I'm assuming the OP is talking about hot wires, but I honestly don't know.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Well just to clarify on the problem - In the given context, each row is all zeros except one element, called as one-hot encoded vector. The task is to count the number of identical vectors and assign them alongside their vectors. So, e.g. for `x = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0 , 0]])`, we would have : `{(0, 0, 0, 0, 1): 1, (1, 0, 0, 0, 0): 2}`.

Comment: @Divakar This encodes the same information and can be expanded to that format if the OP requires it. I suspect he does not, that it's a mild XY Problem.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a case of putting `. . ., sums) if count > 0}` at the end of the dictionary generator:

Answer (score 2):

Here is another interesting solution with sum

```
>> {tuple(v): n for v, n in zip(np.eye(x.shape[1], dtype=int), np.sum(x, axis=0)) 
                if n > 0}
{(0, 0, 1): 1, (1, 0, 0): 2}
```

Comment: Nice. I think our answers are converging... `x.sum(axis=0)`. Additionally, `[1]*len(x[0])` makes it work on any size.

Comment: I like your version better than the one I did if it's necessary that the tuples be provided in a dict. `np.diag()` is perfect for this use.

Answer (score 1):

Lists (including numpy arrays) are unhashable, i.e. they can't be keys of a dictionary. So your precise desired output, a dictionary with keys that look like `[1, 0, 0]` is never possible in Python. To deal with this you need to map your vectors to tuples.

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]])
counts = Counter(map(tuple, x))
```

That will get you:

```
In [12]: counts
Out[12]: Counter({(0, 0, 1): 1, (1, 0, 0): 2})
```